# How to conditionally check if value in Excel Sheet is the same as one another and if true return value of other field in another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've got some Excel Workbook which for purpose of this will have two Sheets in it.

1. Main Sheet where I've got a Person and Company
2. Here I have company but need to conditionally get output like:

if company in 2nd Sheet is the same as in Main then get the Person from main and put it in the column in 2nd Sheet

for example:
Main Sheet has following data: Alina and Company is Dell
then what I want is to check whether I have  Dell in Company column in 2nd sheet and if yes then automatically fill in the name(Alina) in that column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

In the "Main Sheet", the name is in column A and the company is in column B.
In the "2nd Sheet", the company is in column A and you want to fill the corresponding name in column B.
You can use the following formula in the 2nd Sheet to get the name associated with the company:

Using VLOOKUP:

Place this formula in cell B2 of the 2nd Sheet:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, 'Main Sheet'!A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

Drag this formula down for all the rows in your 2nd Sheet.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, if in Main Sheet Company is in Column C and I want Name  in H of 2nd sheet it should be looking like this: =VLOOKUP(A13,'Main Sheet'!C:H,8,FALSE) ?

Comment: just to add more info on actual structure:
Main Sheet is looking like : Col A is Person,  Col B is not important and Col C is Company 

2nd is Company in Col A nad I want to compare it with Col C in Main and get Person corresponding to that company in main and type it into Col H in 2nd Sheet

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? VLOOKUP is  a good option, but XLOOKUP might be easier. It would be =XLOOKUP(A13,"Main Sheet"C,"Main Sheet"H,"")

Comment: currently it is Excel 2024 and checked and I see I have XLOOKUP